# How to yield coroutine with custom IEnumerator class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, coroutine

I found this code for [asynchronously loading models in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync.html). I would like to know how it works so I can do something similar to run an async function and retrieve a value from it inside a coroutine. I could not find anything online using this same construction but I may not have known what to search for, I do not think this example is using async streams.

The code I am interested in is:

```
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        AssetBundleCreateRequest bundleLoadRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(pathToBundle);
        yield return bundleLoadRequest;

        AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle = bundleLoadRequest.assetBundle;
        
        ...
     }
```

I am not sure what kind of object "AssetBundleCreateRequest" is for it to be initialized with an async function, yielded to in the coroutine and then be able to extract a property when the coroutine continues. I would like to run my own async function in a coroutine and extract a return value from it after it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well internally Unity simply creates an `IEnumerator` that `yields` every frame until the async loading task is done.

You could e.g. do something like

```
public static IEnumerator WaitUntilIsDoneAsync(Action action)
{
    var task = task.Run(() => action?.Invoke());

    while (!task.IsCompleted)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Then you could wait for some long taking async stuff do finish via e.g.

```
yield return WaitUntilIsDoneAsync(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

---

Of course in order to make this more useful you would probably rather implement a class like they did where you also store the result of the task for later access etc.

This depends of course a lot on the type you expect to get back.

It could e.g. look like this. Note that I'm no async expert and grabbing this example out of the air .. don't know if it works exactly like that but it is only ment to explain what more or less happens in the background.

So in order to `yield` you just need **any** `IEnumerator`, it doesn't have to be started via `StartCoroutine`.

So you can achieve that by implementing [`IEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator)

```
public class AsyncFileLoadRequest : IEnumerator
{
    private readonly object _contentLock = new object();
    private Task<string> asyncLoadingTask;

    public string File content
    {
        get
        {
            lock(_contentLock)
            {
                return _fileContent;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public AsyncFileLoadRequest(string path)
    {
        asyncLoadTask = File.ReadAllTextAsync(path);
        AwaitTaskAsync();
    }

    #region IEnumerator implementation

    object IEnumerator.Current => null;

    public void Reset() { }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        // As long as this returns true the coroutine will wait
        return !asyncLoadTask.IsCompleted;
    }

    #endregion IEnumerator implementation

    private async void AwaitTaskAsync()
    {
        lock(_contentLock)
        {
            _fileContent = await asyncLoadTask;
        }    
    }
}
```

So you could do something like

```
var request = new AsyncFileLoadRequest(filePath);

yield return request;

var content = request.FileContent;
```

Or use a factory method like they did:

```
public static class FileIOStuff
{
    public static AsyncFileLoadRequest LoadFileAsync(string path)
    {
        return new AsyncFileLoadRequest (path);
    } 
}
```

And the call it like

```
var request = FileIOStuff.LoadFileAsync (filePath);

yield return request;

var content = request.FileContent;
```

Comment: That makes some sense, the part I am still missing though is how you would implement the class so that you can just yield the class variable. I am also not sure how setting the class with the async function works, because it is not like it is initializing code in a constructor.

Comment: @AlexanderFryer yes it is calling a constructor. The static method `AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync` creates and reruns a `new AssetBundleCreateRequest(...)`

Comment: Awesome! This looks like what I wanted. I will give implementing your code a shot to see if I can get something working!

Comment: I figured out I need to implement IEnumerator instead of IEnumerable and have updated my question with my solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlexF thanks for the feedback I updated the answer to use `IEnumerator` instead